# How do I prevent sessions from expiring? I have tried everything and nothing works

Tags: php, .htaccess, session, ini, expired-sessions

I have literally tried everything and nothing works. Sessions still expire after being away for a very short time.

In my header:

```
echo '<script>var refreshTime = 6000000; // every 10 minutes in milliseconds
window.setInterval( function() {
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    url: "refreshSession.php",
    success: function(data) {
    }
});
}, refreshTime );</script>';
```

refreshSession.php:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

Also tried:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6000000);
session_start();
```

Tried this:

```
session_set_cookie_params(6000000);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 6000000);
```

Tried this (.htaccess):

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 6000000
```

I have also tried changing these values within the cPanel PHP options.

I am using GoDaddy and I am not sure if they restrict these or not. Also, if I figure this out, I would like to be able to keep users logged in until they log out instead of specifying a time value.

I would appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: Two remarks that may be of help: 1.) Each PHP page that wants to use session data should call `session_start();`. 2.) `session_start();` should be called before anything else is being output by PHP (even so much as a simple white space character), because cookies are sent in HTTP headers and the headers must be sent before the HTTP body. — If you've verified that this is all accounted for, make sure that the session cookie is actually received by your browser, by inspecting the cookies in your browser.

Comment: If you have other scripts running with different settings (or if you share the session storage directory with other customers on the same server), then the garbage collector triggered by those will also clear your session files. Make sure you are using your own directory (but not one that's publicly readable via the web), and try and set `session.gc_probability` to `0`.

Comment: @CBroe I wrote all scripts myself except a password library and the login/register. Could those possibly have conflicting settings?

Comment: Rather unlikely that those would modify the settings on their own, but of course not impossible.

Comment: Is your jQuery AJAX call being made successfully? "Sessions still expire after being away for a very short time" - What is a "very short time"?